# Mockito InvocationImpl retained across TestSuite tests

Tags: java, memory-leaks, mockito

I have a JUnit Test Suite with ~800 tests. Most of these are wired with Spring and a large number use Mockito to mock/spy behavior. I started running into out of memory errors. While analyzing the hprof dump I noticed that > 30% of heap is consumed by Mockito InvocationImpls that are retained between tests.

Is there some way to clear these after a test class completes? I do not want to use Mockito.reset( mock ) as the mocks initialization varies with each test. If not, it appears I will need to split up the tests to accommodate the leak.

From [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito-dev/Doq3UbDxQ5U) it appears the Mockito team recognizes these are retained as a trade-off of the verification after execution approach. But I'm wondering if someone has found a means to clear these so a large number of unit tests can be strung together in a Suite.

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial work around. In my case the vast majority of the `InvocationImpl` instances were being created during a single test case that used `spy()` to create a Real Partial Mock so one method could be overridden. I am using Mockito 1.10.19, so I switched the partial mock construction from `spy()` to `mock( <class>, withSettings().spiedInstance( realInstance ).defaultAnswer( CALLS_READ_MATHODS ).stubOnly() )`.

While this prevents use of `verify()` on this mock, the `stubOnly()` keeps the mock from storing instances of `InvocationImpl` for each call made to the spy during the test, and significantly decreased heap use.

Since my Mocks are usually created with [Springockito](http://www.springockito.org/) in Spring context files, I needed an ugly rework of the bean definition to match the `mock()` call, as follows. But this allows the spy to be used in Spring-wired domain classes.

```
  <bean id="realInstance" class="<Real Instance Class>" />
  <bean id="instSpySettings" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="withSettings" />
  <bean id="instSpyPartialMock" factory-bean="instSpySettings" factory-method="spiedInstance">
    <constructor-arg>
      <ref local="realInstance" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
  <bean id="instSpyDefaultAnswers" factory-bean="instSpyPartialMock" factory-method="defaultAnswer">
    <constructor-arg><util:constant static-field="org.mockito.Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS"/></constructor-arg>
  </bean>
  <bean id="instSpyStubOnly" factory-bean="instSpyDefaultAnswers" factory-method="stubOnly" />
  <bean id="spyInstance" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="<Real Instance Class>" />
    <constructor-arg>
      <ref local="instSpyStubOnly" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```